# custom tabbable DIV element dotted border is inconsistently applied

Tags: jquery, focus, tabindex, outline

So, I developed some jQuery functionality that finds a <SELECT> element, hides it, and replaces it with a <DIV> full of images.  The <DIV> allows the user to tab into it, then, it listens for left/right arrow keypress events, highlighting the appropriate image (i.e. sets desired img to full opacity, greys out other images). You could compare this to traditional HTML where you could tab to a SELECT and use up/down keys to change selected item.

I use basic HTML added via jQuery to add the new tabbable DIV element:

> jQuery('#desiredOuterDomObjectID').prepend("<div tabindex='0' id='mnu1'>");

This works fine for 2 out of 3 SELECT elements on my form.

So, here's the problem for the 3rd SELECT element: I took my myriad jQuery functions one step further and wrapped them into a proper plugin. The plugin version of my code also creates a perfectly working, tabbable <DIV> with an inner array of IMG objects that can be keyed through. The only difference is: *the dotted highlight border box does not show up on this particular <DIV> element*.

Of course, the goal is to use my "improved" plugin code across the whole HTML form, and dispose of my earlier development efforts.. except I can't seem to make my plugin create a visible border on the otherwise normal tabbable DIV.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the difference between my DIV elements.

It appears that the first two elements (which correctly showed the dotted outline when tabbing them into focus) in addition to my tabindex property that I had added into them, also had some type of *height* property assigned to them.

The rouge DIV element (also containing a tabindex property) DID NOT have any height specified (I thought it might automatically gain a height since it contained IMG elements, similar to the other DIV elements).

Once I used javascript to assign a pixel value to it's style.height property, the dotted border indicating tab focus started displaying correctly.